# Failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:someEnttiy.otherTitles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to test the method https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/service/MoviePersistenceServiceImpl.java#L153. The class has the @Transactional annotation, and the entity's lists are LAZY so there is no problem with using the list while the application is running.
I wrote a test

```
    @Test
public void canCreateOtherTitle() throws ResourceException {
    ...

    this.moviePersistenceService.createOtherTitle(
            otherTitle,
            this.movieRepository.findByIdAndStatus(MOV_1_ID, DataStatus.ACCEPTED)
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)
    );

   ...
}
```

after running tests I get an exception

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.entity.MovieEntity.otherTitles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

in a line

```
    at com.jonki.popcorn.core.jpa.service.MoviePersistenceServiceImpl.createOtherTitle(MoviePersistenceServiceImpl.java:162)
```

here in the code
https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/service/MoviePersistenceServiceImpl.java#L162

Why is this happening? The method works correctly during normal operation of the application, but during the tests it throws an exception.

The whole test
 https://pastebin.com/fewHBUff

Answer (score 0):

Your various service methods work fine, because you have annotated the whole service class as `@Transactional`. This means that Spring will automatically open up a Session that is going to be used by Hibernate to initialize the lazy collection.

On the other hand, neither your test class or your test method are annotated with this, hence the error you're getting. You can try to annotate the test method with `@Transactional` and I suppose that this will solve your problem.

Comment: I added the @Transactional annotation over the method https://pastebin.com/9bfaqeU2 but I'm getting an error
 ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start new transaction without ending existing transaction
```.

Comment: Do you know what else I can try to do?